# How to reference other Workbooks by filename in VBA with same prefix

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a very simple copy & paste Macro to pull data from a daily generated reports and paste it into a their respective sheets in a Master document. I've gotten the macro to work based on the filename, however after opening these documents every day it's likely that it will have the suffix (002) and so on attached. I've attempted to create variables as below, but I get the Else Without If error.

```
Sub SEI_Data_Copy_Paste()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim STKQRM As Workbook
Dim Production As Workbook
Dim OpenOrder As Workbook
Dim Location As Workbook


For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
If wb.Name Like "STKQRM PO Data for Planning*" Then Set STKQRM = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Production for Planning*" Then Set Production = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Open Orders for Planning*" Then Set OpenOrder = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Stock Locations Pivot*" Then Set Location = wb
End If
Next wb
```

I imagine it's a fairly basic error, but every other resource is talking about opening or activating files based on different filenames which doesn't address what I'm trying to do. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: because you have a one line if statement. put the part after ```then``` on a new line for ```if``` and each ```elseif``` Or use a Select Case.

Comment: If you are using elseif then the code after the Thens needs to be on a separate line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just an `If` you can do:

```
If wb.Name Like "STKQRM PO Data for Planning*" Then Set STKQRM = wb
```

Note that there is no `End If` here.

You could change each `ElseIf` to an `If` and have:

```
If wb.Name Like "STKQRM PO Data for Planning*" Then Set STKQRM = wb
If wb.Name Like "Production for Planning*" Then Set Production = wb
If wb.Name Like "Open Orders for Planning*" Then Set OpenOrder = wb
If wb.Name Like "Stock Locations Pivot*" Then Set Location = wb
```

However, that has a different flow, each `If` would be checked instead of moving on after a successful match so you wouldn't want to that.

To incorporate `ElseIf` you need to separate the comparison and the subsequent action:

```
If wb.Name Like "STKQRM PO Data for Planning*" Then 
    Set STKQRM = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Production for Planning*" Then 
    Set Production = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Open Orders for Planning*" Then 
    Set OpenOrder = wb
ElseIf wb.Name Like "Stock Locations Pivot*" Then 
    Set Location = wb
End If
```

You could also do a `Select Case`:

```
Select Case True
    Case (wb.Name Like "STKQRM PO Data for Planning*")
        Set STKQRM = wb
    Case (wb.Name Like "Production for Planning*")
        Set Production = wb
    Case (wb.Name Like "Open Orders for Planning*")
        Set OpenOrder = wb
    Case (wb.Name Like "Stock Locations Pivot*")
        Set Location = wb
    Case Else
        'Just for show
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation.
I decided to go with the Select Case you had written out at the bottom, but I end up getting Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set. 

I have some copy and pastes written out towards the bottom, but the error is popping up at the Select Case wb.Name line.

Comment: Yeah I messed up the select, sorry about that the edit should fix it. The select needs to within you wb loop aswell.

Comment: The edited Select Case worked. However, I'm running into Run-time error 91 when I try to utilize the variable as such: 
STKQRM.Sheets("STKQRM PO Data for Planning").Range("A1:Z2000").Copy  (Note: this is code that I didn't include in the original question because it was working when I wrote out the workbook filename explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure STKQRM was matched against? That error means the variable wasn't set

Comment: I realized I had not enabled editing on the other workbooks. It works now. Thank you so much for your help!